# Setting values at run time for APP_LOCALE defined in .env file in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I started learning the Lumen micro-framework recently and I am in need to change during runtime the value for the APP_LOCALE key that is defined in my .env file. My goal is to switch the language at run time to print different translations of a certain String defined in my languages files.

In the Lumen documentation it is written:

> To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper

So I tried the fallowing in a test controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController{
    public function show_test(){
        echo(trans('testfile.greetings'));
        config(['app.LOCALE' => 'en']);
        echo(trans('testfile.greetings'));
    }
}
```

In my .env file my "default" APP_LOCALE is set to 'fr' and the result of calling this controller print my string in french twice instead of the expected one time in french then one time in english.

How can I change the value at runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently someone else posted the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244624/lumen-fails-to-change-locale) a few days after me and got the answer which is:

```
app('translator')->setLocale('en');
```

Answer (score 1):

The key in `config/app.php` is `locale`, not `LOCALE`, so you want `config(['app.locale' => 'en'])`. The name in `.env` is not necessarily the name in the `config` folder's files.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I just tried with locale in lower case like you suggested, but it is not changing the result that I get. Still twice in french.

Comment: @JulienMN Does `\Config::set('app.locale', 'en');` work?

Comment: You can pass locale into `trans()`. See the [API here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.html#method_trans).

Comment: @BrokenBinary Useful in some situations, but most times you'd be changing the locale at runtime it'd be to translate all of them, not individual ones (like for a language switcher based on a session value).

Comment: Right, but in this instance @JulienMN says his goal is to switch the language at run time. That sounds to me like he wants to display it in multiple languages on the same page.

Comment: @BrokenBinary I took that as "I don't want to change it in the `.env` file".

Comment: Basically I just want to change the locale based on an action from the user (a click on the language switcher). The application is french by default (defined in the .env)

Comment: @ceejayoz: `\Config::set('app.locale', 'en');` errors out.

Comment: @ceejayoz Sorry I should have included the error message in my previous message. Here it is:
`Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in /var/www/sites/testproject-apiv4/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php on line 10`

I tried adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` but it is still the same errror.