# Lumen fails to change locale

Tags: php, lumen

I have an almost fresh installation of Lumen.

I have a `POST` route which leads to one Controller. In the request I send `lang` parameter with a string value.

```
public function form(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('lang')) {
        app('config')->set('app.locale', $request->input('lang'));
    }
    return view('form');
}
```

I have one folder more in my `/resources/lang/` folder called `bg`. In this folder I have simple file which has an array just like in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` - called `static.php`.

In the view I'm displaying I have few lines that say:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="input-default" placeholder="{{trans('static.enter_email')}}"/>
```

The text I've set in those lang files in `resources/lang/...` are properly displayed, **but** I cannot change the locale before displaying the form.

For example, if in my **dotenv** file I set:

`APP_LOCALE=en`

And load the view the strings in `resources/lang/en/static.php` are loaded.
If I change the `APP_LOCALE` to `bg` and load the view again, I get the strings from `resources/lang/bg/static.php`.

All I want is to set the locale before rendering the view, which doesn't seem to work with the code (in my controller) I provided above.

Also I couldn't find any information about localization in Lumen on the official site, but I suppose it supports such, since `trans()` is working.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $app('config') not app('config') ?

Comment: `Shouldn't it be $app('config') not app('config')` what do you want to say?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are changing the config after it is loaded, which has no effect. To change the locale at runtime use the `setLocale()` method on the app instance:

`app()->setLocale($request->input('lang'));`

### Edit

The first answer seem to only work on Laravel. To change the locale at runtime with Lumen use this:

`app('translator')->setLocale($request->input('lang'));`

Comment: Are you sure that this method is present in Lumen? Because I get this error: `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::setLocale()`

Comment: You're right. I just assumed that it would work with Lumen as well. Sorry about that. I've updated my answer with new information.

Comment: Thanks it works now! Obviously, Lumen's docs are not that new-to-laravel developers friendly.

Comment: In `bootstrap/app.php`, I added `app('translator')->setLocale('fr');` and that doesn't work with Lumen 5.1. How to solve that ?

Comment: I have more than 20 languages in my lumen api project and each language has more than 50 files and each file has more than 100 labels/messages to translate. Could you please suggest me how can translate all the files in all the languages by command line or any easy method instead of changing language file manually one-by-one. Thanks a lot. Look forward to hear you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing locale at the runtime varying depends on the framework.
You can use facade or helper function:

For **Lumen**:

```
Lang::setLocale('lang');
```

or

```
app('translator')->setLocale('lang');
```

For **Laravel**:

```
App::setLocale('lang');
```

or

```
app()->setLocale('lang');
```

Comment: I am using Lumen 8.0 version and `app('translator')->setLocale('en');` helped me to set english language. Thanks dear.