# How to change LOCALE language on Lumen

Tags: php, locale, lumen

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244624/lumen-fails-to-change-locale), but it don't answers me.

I have set `APP_LOCALE=fr` in the `.env` file, but I still get date in english format :

```
string 'Thursday, 09h00' (length=15)
```

And I would like to get :

```
string 'Jeudi, 09h00' (length=12)
```

How to change from english to french on [Lumen Framework](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation) ?

(Added PHP tag to be more seen)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In lumen you cannot set the locale in your config. You can however change the locale in code by using `app('translator')->setLocale($locale);`.

In my own projects I set the default locale by adding `app('translator')->setLocale('fr');` in the `/bootstrap/app.php` file before the line `return $app;`.

Comment: Come back toward you. In `bootstrap/app.php`, I added `app('translator')->setLocale('fr');` and that doesn't work with Lumen 5.1. How to solve that ?

Comment: Sadly, Lumen no longer trigger an event on locale change, so Carbon is no longer synchronized, you have to run `\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale($locale)` too if you display dates with Carbon.

Comment: This help-me with custom validation by language. Thanks!

Comment: I am using lumen 8.0 version and it works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68844036/10329023