# Lumen (laravel) translation in controller

Tags: php, laravel, translation, lumen

I need to translate strings which are used in (email-)jobs and controllers.

I read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization so I know you can get in in the view with:

```
echo trans("messages.welcome");
```

But it's an Lumen api and I do not use the view.

How can i get the translator in a controller or a job.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the translator in controller you need to use it like below

```
//include in your controller
use Lang;

//in code you get values like
Lang::get('messages.error');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks!, the complete use statement (in my case) is `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;`

Comment: It's because you don't have `'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class` as alias in your app.php

Answer (score 8):

`trans` it's a global function, so you  can use it directly from your controller or `Closure`

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    echo trans('messages.welcome');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**I am using Lumen 8.0 version:**

**To set new local language:**

`$request->input('lang')` can have any language code eg. `en` or you can set it manully by passing language code as parameter in `setLocale` function.

```
app('translator')->setLocale($request->input('lang'));
```

**To get current local language:**

```
app('translator')->getLocale();
```

**output: en**

This worked for me. I hope, this will also help you :)