# Impossible to modify the localization in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

This topic has already been placed and solved, but following the Lumen update to version 5.1, it no longer works!

According to a question I asked [some times ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630039/how-to-change-locale-language-on-lumen), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244624/lumen-fails-to-change-locale), we just have to add :

```
app()->setLocale('fr');
```

to `bootsrap/app.php` or in controller function to make changes become active.

But it seems don't work today.

After apply the code above, I should get my date change to french, but I still get the english format (ex: `Wednesday 18 November 2015` instead of `Mercredi 18 Novembre 2015`).

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is about Carbon. You can read [the documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) and the Carbon examples :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Wednesday 21 May 1975

// In your case (to be more accurate) :
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'French');
ucfirst($dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y à %Hh%M')); // Mercredi 21 mai 2015 à 14h25
```

And you should use setlocale in lumen like this (of course in **bootstrap/app.php** file) :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
Dotenv::load(__DIR__ . '/../');

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fr_FR.utf-8', 'fr_FR@euro', 'fr_FR', 'fr', 'French');
```

Or you can using this package: https://github.com/jenssegers/date and using:

In the **bootstrap/app.php** file :

```
// ...

$app->register(Jenssegers\Date\DateServiceProvider::class);
class_alias(Jenssegers\Date\Date::class, 'Date');
Date::setLocale(env('APP_LOCALE'));
```

And in **your model** :

```
// ...
protected $dates = ['x_date'];
public function getXDateAttribute() {
    return Date::parse($this->attributes['x_date'])
             ->format('l j F Y H:i:s');
}

public function setXDateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['x_date'] =
    Date::createFromFormat('l j F Y H:i:s', $date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works perfectly on independant classes I use, and classes using Carbon too. Excellent answer. Well appreciated !